# Remove Windows OS from Multiboot

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, multi-boot

I had XP on my computer.

Later, I installed Windows 10, and from my understanding Windows 10 installed a bootloader to allow multiple booting.

Now, I need to keep only the XP and want to remove Windows 10 completely.
The installation is on separate drive, so if I format the drive of Windows 10 ( from Windows XP), will it work ?

Answer (score 1):

Open “**Run**”, type “***msconfig***” and enter with enter. On Boot tab, you can manually delete the Windows 10 boot entry, then, re-start into Windows XP and format the Windows 10 installation drive.

It is always recommended to back up your system and important data before any change.